# Create Select clause within Stored Procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, select, mysql, runtime

I have two tables coming which has data from two different systems. I need to reconcile the data in these two tables 
The column mapping needs to be made configurable.

E.g.:

```
Table A                                                        Table B
Col1A, Col2A                                                Col1B, Col2B

MappingTable 
Col1A = Col1B
Col2A= Col2B
```

So I would need to have two result sets like this based on the mappings in the table.This needs to be decided dynamically. i.e. `Select _____ from A`. `The _____ needs to be filled dynamically.`

```
Select Col1A, Col2A from A
Select Col2B, Col1B from B
```

Is this possible in [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [UNION clause](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/sql/interactive_sql_tutorial/sql_union.php) if the column sets are similar (if they're not you won't be able to combine their results in a meaningful way, anyway).

```
select col1a, col2a from A
union
select col1b, col2b from b
```